# Access a single SQLAlchemy object through JS

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, flask

I am attempting to update most of my site data based on the selection in a select2 field by using on change. I have followed tutorials that use `fetch` to create a JSON file with information pulled from the database. Although, this scenario is slightly different because I am trying to access one object for use in my JS to update some site HTML.

I have tried using `fetch` to return the object but I have found it returns an array with random data about the URL.

### views.py

```
@app.route('/selected_room/<int:room_id>')
def selected_room(room_id):
    room = Room.query.filter_by(id=room_id).first_or_404()

    return room
```

### returns:

```
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "basic"
url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/room/2"
```

I've already posted some of this code above but here is everything I currently have set up.

### views.py

```
@app.route('/selected_room/<int:room_id>')
def selected_room(room_id):
    room = Room.query.filter_by(id=room_id).first_or_404()

    return room
```

### js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#rooms').on('change', function() {
        var room_id = $(this).val();

        fetch('/room/' + room_id).then(function(data) {
            // this console.log is me testing to see what data returns
            console.log(room_id, data, data.room_id, data.room, data.rooms);
        });
    });
});
```

In reality, I am looking for the JS replacement of `{{ object.id(etc) }}`. Either I am totally off and this can't be done or I am simply on the wrong track. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's think this through systematically.

`fetch` is documented at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch). You seem to have called it with the right arguments: `resource`, which can be a URL, and no `init` argument (which is optional).

It says that `fetch` returns a promise, and that promise resolves to a `Response` object. If you're not familiar with promises, you can follow the link to `Promise` from there. If you are, you'll know that the `data` argument is the `Response` object.

If you follow the link to see what a `Response` object is, you'll see that it contains fields such as `headers`, `ok`, `redirected`, etc. This seems to match what you've written in your question, under the heading "returns:". So I'm assuming that the return value you've listed is the `data` object, as displayed by the `console.log`.

So the question is: Given a `Response` (the variable `data`), how do you extract the body of the response? There are several ways of accessing the response body in the documentation for `Response`. You can use `data.body`, `data.arrayBuffer()`, `data.blob()`, `data.formData()`, `data.json()` or `data.text()`, depending on what kind of response it is. I don't know much Python or any flask at all, I don't know what `Room` is on the server side, so I don't know what the response is like.

Comment: So I gave this a try and used a few just to test it out. Most notably I keep getting `rooms: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]` as a response instead of the array I need. It might be possible for me to filter the array if I get it to pass correctly to my JS, but that isn't the case as of now. Also thanks for the help!

Comment: In lieu of my last response, I realized those `objects` can be defined further. I tested again with `console.log('rooms [0].room_number: ' + data.rooms[0].room_number);` and this returned the proper number. This means the only thing remaining is to figure out what position the selected room is in. Any ideas?

Comment: That's strange. The Python code definitely seems like it should be just returning one room, yet the javascript code says it's received 4 of them. Unless... I notice the route in the Python code is `'/selected_room/<int:room_id>'`, but the javascript is calling `'/room/' + room_id`. If this is the case then it's not even calling that API at all, it's calling some other API. What happens if you change the client-side code to match the API?

Comment: I went ahead and fixed that route to match the API as you stated and it was successful. I was calling the wrong route, which does exist, but it is used for something else. Thanks for the help @David Knipe